# Need to port Visual Basic .NET code to Java

Tags: java, vb.net

```vb
    Try
        Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(Mapfile & ".txt")
        'Dim intValue As String = ""
        Dim strLine As String = ""
        Dim X As Integer = 0
        Dim Y As Integer = 0

        Do Until sr.EndOfStream
            strLine = sr.ReadLine
            strLine = strLine.Replace(strLine.LastIndexOf(","), "")
            For Each item As String In Split(strLine, ",", -1)
                'MsgBox("X:" & X & " Y:" & Y & "= " & item)
                If item = "" Then
                    item = 0
                End If
                If X <= MapWidth Then
                    Map(X, Y, 0) = Int(item)
                End If

                X = X + 1
            Next

            X = 0
            Y = Y + 1
        Loop

        sr.Close()
        sr.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Map: " & Mapfile & " could not be loaded." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "ERROR")
        IsOn = False
    End Try
```

Trying to port this code over from Visual Basic To Java. I've Tried using Buffered Reader but nothing seems To Make it happen. The Code Above is for Visual Basic, The Code below is my java port that doesnt seem to be working the same. http://pastebin.com/freXYTi3

```
public void readFile(Context c) {

    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {


      br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getAssets().open("map1.txt")));
      String line = null;
      String newLine = "";
      int x = 0;
      int y = 0;

      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        int length = line.length();
        String lastChar = line.substring(length-1);

        if (lastChar.contains(",")) {
            newLine = line.substring(0,length-1) + "";
        }
        //line = line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(",")) + "";
        for (String str : line.split(",", -1)) {
        System.out.println(str);
            if(str == ""){
                str = "0";
            }
            if(x <= mapwidth){

                System.out.println(x + " " + y);
                int N = Integer.parseInt(str);
                Map[x][y] = N;

            }

            x = x + 1;
        }
        x = 0;
        y = y + 1;
      }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
      try {
        if (br != null)
          br.close();
      }
      catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: "nothing seems to give me want i want" is hardly a detailed description of what's going wrong. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Why not post a rough version of your Java conversion and we can help you correct it.

Comment: I can post the code i wrote. Hold on

Comment: Just posted the java code, It does Cycles threw it but it Crashes on the last line of the file

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from the crash, or at least the first line that points to something in your code (As a rule this is usually the Most Important Line in all of Java debugging--the topmost line in the stack trace that points to code in one of your packages)

Comment: What about scanner? Useful little thing =D

Comment: I'm not sure the exception stack has any relevance to the code above. Have a look at what you have on GamePanel.java:64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the exact line you are failing on (the error codes give line numbers, but I don't know the correlation to your file), the only thing I notice is that this line:

```
if(x <= mapwidth){
```

MIGHT be a one-off bug.  I think VB is 1-based and Java is zero based, but it's just a guess that you might want < rather than <=  Can you let us know what line the NPE was on.

Also this is wrong:

```
if(str == ""){
```

needs to be "str.equals("")" or "str.length()==0"

but I don't see anything that could cause an NPE within the loop

Also you assign newline in the loop and you never use it within that scope, so if it exits and you have another "newline" and you expect it to be set--don't hold your breath.

Comment: Map[x][y] = N; is where it crashes at in java!

Answer (score 0):

If you post the error you are getting then you might get a better answer but without knowing the content you are trying to parse it looks like you are making assumptions around the data you are parsing.